# Getting selected radio button value, on (ionChange) in radio-group , ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I want to get the selected radio button value, on (ionChange) event in radio-group in Ionic2.

My Html code is

```
<ion-list radio-group *ngFor="let question of mcqData; let i= index;" (ionChange)="mcqAnswer(i)">
  <ion-list-header>
    {{question.questionText}}
  </ion-list-header>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionA}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="1"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionB}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="2"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionC}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="3"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionD}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="4"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

How can I get ion-radio value in mcqQuesiton() on (ion-change).

I have number or radio-groups on a single page, as it is a multiple choice question page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [ionSelect](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/radio/RadioButton/) event of  `<ion-radio>` to pass the value.

```
...
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionA}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="1" (ionSelect)="mcqAnswer(i,1)"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionB}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="2" (ionSelect)="mcqAnswer(i,2)"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
...
```

In your typescript (.ts) file it will be something like

```
mcqAnswer(questionID,answer){
...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can pass through $event to your onChange method. E.g.

In your html:

```
<ion-list radio-group *ngFor="let question of mcqData; let i= index;" (ionChange)="mcqAnswer($event)">
  <ion-list-header>
    {{question.questionText}}
  </ion-list-header>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionA}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="1"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionB}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="2"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionC}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="3"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionD}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="4"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In your Typescript:

```
function mcqAnswer(value)
{
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: a snippet of code demonstrating the usage would be more helpful

Comment: Sorry I was strapped for time when I commented. I'll update the answer now.

Comment: This does not console log the value but the $event, use $event.target.value

Answer (score 1):

ionic v6: use ngmodel

```
<ion-radio-group  [(ngModel)]="McAns" *ngFor="let question of mcqData; let i= index;" (ionChange)="mcqAnswer($event)">
  <ion-list-header>
    {{question.questionText}}
  </ion-list-header>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionA}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="1"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{question.optionB}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  value="2"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-radio-group>
```

on  (ionChange)="mcqAnswer($event)"

```
 mcqAnswer(eve) {
    console.log(this.McAns)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways .one is to use ionSelect.below is an example

```
  <ion-item >
    <ion-label><h2>You entered:</h2>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-radio color="success"  slot="start" [value]="enteredAddress" (ionSelect)="populateSuggestion($event)"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label><h2>Suggested Address:</h2>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-radio  color="success" slot="start" [value]="suggestedAddress" (ionSelect)="populateSuggestion($event)" ></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

</ion-radio-group>
```

way 2 is use access the native DOM element using ViewChild.
html:

ts:
 @ViewChild('radio', { read: ElementRef, static: false }) radio: ElementRef;

Answer (score -1):

Choose Category

```
   <ion-item *ngFor="let category of subcategories; let index=index;">
      <ion-label>{{category}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio [value]="category"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
```

In your `.ts` file:

```
selectedValue($event){
  console.log($event);
}
```